# Property $(T)$ for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: reference-request, expander-graphs, cayley-graphs, property-t

(This is in part a request for references and in part a somewhat pedagogical question.)

I gave a course on expanders seven years ago, and I am giving a course on expanders again now. We will soon do Margulis's constructions of expander graphs. I'm minded to first give a self-contained proof in one class (expansion for Schreier graphs of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})\ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})^2$, following Gabber-Galil and Jimbo-Maruocka's new proofs of Margulis's results, but in a slightly more abstract way - no reason not to use the Ping-Pong lemma and so forth), then do expansion for Cayley graphs of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/N \mathbb{Z})$ (as I did seven years ago), and then do property $T$.

(a) Whom should I cite for the proof of expansion for Cayley graphs of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ based on Gabber-Galil/Jimbo-Maruocka (as opposed to the usual proof via property $(T)$ for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$? (Or did I come up with it myself (not very hard, given what I was given) only to then forget about it?)

(b) Proving full Property $T$ (first for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\ltimes \mathbb{R}^2$, then for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$) in this way doesn't seem hard, but surely that is also standard?

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2$ does not have Property T (but it indeed has Property $\tau$ with respect to congruence subgroups —  for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ this is due to Brooks, I think)

Comment: Ah - surely it has relative property $T$?

Comment: Yes. But this is not enough to prove the expansion for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})\ltimes (\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^2$. For this, at the left-hand side you really need Property $\tau$ wrt congruence subgroups.

Comment: Yes, going from relative property T to property T this way is standard.

Comment: @YCor Surely one can prove expansion for Cayley graphs of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$ without proving expansion for Cayley graphs of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ (unless I am making a mistake somewhere). An argument essentially as in Gabber-Galil/Jimbo-Maruocka suffices for any unitary representation of the group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^2$.

Comment: Well no, if you deal with all unitaries of the semidirect product, you also deal with all unitaries of the quotient. If you only mean the spectral gap for the Cayley graphs, it's different since you don't consider all unitaries.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Right - this is clearly a proof of expansion for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$, starting from expansion for the Schreier graph of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$, modelled after the usual proof of property $T$ starting from relative property $T$. But is this proof (a minor variation on something standard) due to my past self, or to someone else I should credit? I don't know!

Comment: @YCor Let me see. I see in my old notes that what I can actually prove (with ease - similarly to Gabber-Galil, but in a way more nicely, in that Fourier analysis comes in out of its own will) is that, for any unitary representation $\rho:G_N=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})\ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2\curvearrowright V$ and any generating set $S\subset G = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\ltimes \mathbb{Z}^2$,  if $v\in V$ ($|v|_2=1$) satisfies $\pi(s) v - v|<\epsilon \; \forall s\in S$, then $|h v - v| \ll_S \epsilon \; \forall h\in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$.

Comment: @YCor From that, one can get expansion for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$, by the argument modelled after the usual proof, etc.

Comment: One also gets relative property $(\tau)$ with respect to the "congruence subgroups" of $G$ right away. (In fact that's pretty much what I just said.) Now I think (let me not be lazy and actually do this once I am done typing, unless someone has an argument why it isn't possible) essentially the same proof should be enough to get relative property $T$ for $G$. Surely that does imply that the Schreier graph of $G_N=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}) \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$ acting on $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$ is an expander.

Comment: But you are right, expansion for the Cayley graph of $G_N$ wouldn't follow. However, expansion for the Cayley graph of $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ would follow in the usual way.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be the way of Burger and Shalom, basically. I'm guessing that I may have learned it from Appendix D.4 of Kowalski's The Large Sieve...

Comment: Maybe, here's something interesting to you. Colin de Verdière's note for his lecture in 1994 [ p53 in http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~ycolver/All-Articles/98a.pdf ] already uses the bounded generation method.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Nice! So that's after Burger and before Shalom?

Comment: I'm no historian, but yes if it was done in 1994.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question of who decided to just skip property $(T)$ and use the bounded generation method to prove expansion for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$. In context, it's a very small achievement, so it may have been past-Harald. Who knows.